# Single shortcut to open selected path in explorer?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file

I frequently copy a file path from a chat program, open the run dialog with Win+r, and paste the path to open the file.

I'm wondering if I can simplify this:

- To two steps (open the path on the clipboard)
- Or one step? (treat highlighted text as a path and open in explorer)

The solution should be possible to invoke with a keyboard shortcut while another program has focus (e.g. the chat program where the path is listed)

Is this possible using a batch or powershell script, or would it need to be a small program running in the background?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to have a hotkey or open a highlighted path immediately, you could use Autohotkey https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/109850-open-highlighted-filepath/

Comment: Thanks Simon, this is exactly the behavior I'm trying to achieve, but I'd like to do it without 3rd party software so it is more easily portable and shareable.

Comment: so i found and edited a script that basically emulates this autohotkey behaviour, but as of right now it can only get single keys (e.g X, Y, F11), but not keycombinations (e.g CTRL + X). I'll read up on that a bit and post it as an answer when I'm finished

Answer (score 2):

Copying this from the response by @SimonS above just so it shows up as an answer.  I'm doing the same thing using Autohotkeys shown in his link so that any text I currently have highlighted is executed using the windows 'Run' command.

"if you want to have a hotkey or open a highlighted path immediately, you could use Autohotkey [http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/109850-open-highlighted-filepath"](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/109850-open-highlighted-filepath%22)

If anyone knows how I can attribute this answer to jake please let me know.

Comment: I think you want to attribute it to @SimonS

Comment: Thank you. Updated the text but can't seem to insert a proper link to his comment from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a simple powershell command does the trick for the two-step version:

```
get-clipboard|invoke-item
```

This works as a shortcut without even requiring a dedicated script file:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "get-clipboard|invoke-item"
```

It gets kludgey from there:

- You can only assign a keyboard shortcut if the shortcut is saved on
  the desktop
- You can't use the Win key in shortcuts
- You can't keep the
  powershell console from flashing on the screen for a second

But maybe that's the best-case without 3rd party software.

Comment: But, 'invoke-action' is not a native PowerShell cmdlet/function. So, ether that is a custom function you ginned up or downloaded from elsewhere. I do see though in your actual command, you are using 'Invoke-Item' to achieve your use case. As for only on the desktop, well, you can put it on the taskbar, in position 1-10 (actually 1..9,0), and the use WinKey+ThePositionNumber as your hotkey, without having to create one. Also, you can prevent the flash, but that's a bit more work.

Comment: Indeed, `action` was a typo for `item` when I wrote that up. Thanks for the tip on the taskbar shortcuts. Didn't know about those!

Comment: No worries. The taskbar thing has been possible since WinXP.  ;-} and I've been using it ever since for my regularly used stuff. Since it is WinKey based, no matter what you have on your screen (active or not), WInKey+# is always possible. Well, not in some kiosk mode stuff, but, you know. Just remember to use the numbers across the top of your keyboard, the number pads don't work for this, well, not on any keyboard I've used to date.